# How to Determine actual MIME type of content?

Tags: android, mime-types

How to get the actual mime type of file(like image/video/doc etc.) even if I change the extension of the file?

I am sorry if I am repeating this question but I tried a lot but could not find a proper answer.

I tried this code

```
public static String getMimefromuri(Uri uri) {
        String mimetype = null;
            ContentResolver cr = GlobalVariables.mActivity.getContentResolver();
            mimetype = cr.getType(uri);
            Log.d("getmime_katype", "" + mimetype + " uri");
            return mimetype;

    }
```

It works fine when it has the right file extension but if I change the extension of file (like if I change the extension of an image file from jpg to mp4) it shows me video/mp4 in the result.

I have also tried some libraries like

1.jmimemagic
2.apache tika

but it didn't work.

so How to get the actual mime type of content even if the extension is not right.

Comment: IMHO, what you want is impractical. There are [hundreds of registered MIME types](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml), let alone unregistered ones. For each of those MIME types, you would need to work out an algorithm to determine if a file's contents are encoded in a way that is compatible with that MIME type. However, bear in mind that your rename-the-file issue is not a problem specifically with `getType()` on `ContentResolver`, but with the specific `Uri` that you are using.

Comment: String mimeType = null;
        try {
            mimeType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromStream(is);
            Log.d("getmimefile",""+mimeType);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("getmimefile",""+e.getMessage());

        } . this code gives me exact mimetype but it only works for image not for video.